# Woocommerce CRM connect

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to connect my Woocommerce to a CRM. They gave me this example code.
My question:
In what file do i need to add this code in Woocommerce.

```
class SimplicateApi {

    public $authentication_key;
    public $authentication_secret;
    public $api_url;

    public function __construct($domain, $key, $secret){

        $this->authentication_key = $key;
        $this->authentication_secret = $secret;
        $this->api_url  = 'https://'.$domain.'/api/v2';
        }

    public function makeApiCall($method, $url, $payload = NULL) {
        // Generate the list of headers to always send.
        $headers = array(
                "User-Agent: simplicate-koppeling",// Sending a User-Agent header is a best practice.
                "Authentication-Key: ".$this->authentication_key,
                "Authentication-Secret: ".$this->authentication_secret,
                "Accept: application/json",             // Always accept JSON response.
        );

        $endpoint = $this->api_url . $url;

        $curl = curl_init($endpoint);

        switch(strtoupper($method)) {
            case "GET":
                // Nothing to do, GET is the default and needs no
                // extra headers.
                break;
            case "POST":
                // Add a Content-Type header (IMPORTANT!)
                $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
                break;
            case "PATCH":
                // Add a Content-Type header (IMPORTANT!)
                $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
                break;
            case "DELETE":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
                break;
            default:
                exit;
        }

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if (self::isFailure($httpCode)) {
            return array('errorNumber' => $httpCode,
                    'error' => 'Request  returned HTTP error '.$httpCode,
                    'request_url' => $url);
        }

        $curl_errno = curl_errno($curl);
        $curl_err = curl_error($curl);

        if ($curl_errno) {
            $msg = $curl_errno.": ".$curl_err;
            curl_close($curl);
            return array('errorNumber' => $curl_errno,
                    'error' => $msg);
        }
        else {
            error_log("Response: ".$response);
            curl_close($curl);
            return json_decode($response, true);


        }
    }

    public static function isFailure($httpStatus){
        // Simplistic check for failure HTTP status
        return ($httpStatus >= 400);
    }
}



$SimplicateApi = new SimplicateApi('yourdomain.simplicate.nl','yourapikey','yourapisecret');

// pepare the payload to create an organization
$org_payload = array(
        'name' => $variable_with_organization_name,
        'phone' => $variable_with_organization_phone,
        'email' => $variable_with_organization_email,
        'note' => $variable_with_note,
        'relation_type' => array(
            'id'=>'' //provide the relationtypeid, f.e. relationtype:796ce0d318a2f5db515efc18bba82b90
        ),
        'visiting_address' => array(
            'country_code'          =>  'NL'
        ), // can be extented with other address data
        'postal_address' => array(
            'country_code'          =>  'NL'
        ) // can be extented with other address data
);

// add the organization to the CRM
$organization = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('POST','/crm/organization',json_encode($org_payload));
```

And nother question.
How about this part:

```
// pepare the payload to create an organization
$org_payload = array(
        'name' => $variable_with_organization_name,
        'phone' => $variable_with_organization_phone,
        'email' => $variable_with_organization_email,
        'note' => $variable_with_note,
```

Where do i get these variables from woocommerce?

Answer (score 1):

you need  Add custom api route
first technique :
inside woocommerce-ac.php add :

```html
add_action('woocommerce_api_loaded', 'wpc_register_wp_api_endpoints');
function wpc_register_wp_api_endpoints() {
include_once( 'woo-includes/api/v2/class-wc-api-carts.php' );
add_filter('woocommerce_api_classes', 'filter_woocommerce_api_classes', 10, 1);
}
function filter_woocommerce_api_classes($array) {
$cart = array(
'WC_API_Carts',
);
return array_merge($array, $cart);
}
```

and inside woo-includes/api/v2 add class-wc-api-customs.php; that is done
[full details](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/woocommerce/woocommerce-add-custom-api-route)